# Display multiple Google Charts on One Page C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have the following C# that pulls data from Stored Procedures, however the `fee_chart` chart doesn't render. But if I remove the `result_chart` and classes associated with it (`BindChartResult` and `GetChartDataResult` ) it renders fine, but I need both to display. I'm unsure where I have made an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## C#

```
public partial class feestatistics: System.Web.UI.Page {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

   if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    string query = "SELECT DISTINCT year.year_title, year.year_id FROM year";
    DataTable dt = GetData(query);
    ddlyear.DataSource = dt;
    ddlyear.DataTextField = "year_title";
    ddlyear.DataValueField = "year_id";
    ddlyear.DataBind();
    ddlyear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", "All"));
    ddlyear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" - Select -", ""));
   }

  }


  private void BindChartFees() {
    DataTable dsChartData = new DataTable();
    StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();

    try {
     dsChartData = GetChartDataFees();

     strScript.Append(@ "<script type='text/javascript'>  
       google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['corechart']
       }); < /script>  

       < script type = 'text/javascript' >

       function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['status', 'total'], ");

          foreach(DataRow row in dsChartData.Rows) {
           strScript.Append("['" + row["status"] + "'," + row["total"] + "],");
          }
          strScript.Remove(strScript.Length - 1, 1);
          strScript.Append("]);");

          strScript.Append(@ " var options = {     
           title: 'Fee Statistics',
           is3D: false,
          };
          ");

          strScript.Append(@ "var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('fee_chart'));          
           chart.draw(data, options);
          }
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          ");
          strScript.Append(" </script>");

          ltScripts.Text = strScript.ToString();
         } catch {}

        }

        private void BindChartResult() {
          DataTable dsChartData = new DataTable();
          StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();

          try {
           dsChartData = GetChartDataResult();

           strScript.Append(@ "<script type='text/javascript'>  
             google.load('visualization', '1', {
              packages: ['corechart']
             }); < /script>  

             < script type = 'text/javascript' >

             function drawChart() {
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['status', 'total'], ");

                foreach(DataRow row in dsChartData.Rows) {
                 strScript.Append("['" + row["status"] + "'," + row["total"] + "],");
                }
                strScript.Remove(strScript.Length - 1, 1);
                strScript.Append("]);");

                strScript.Append(@ " var options = {     
                 title: 'Pass/Fail Statistics',
                 is3D: false,
                };
                ");

                strScript.Append(@ "var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('result_chart'));          
                 chart.draw(data, options);
                }
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                ");
                strScript.Append(" </script>");

                ltScripts.Text = strScript.ToString();
               } catch {}

              }

              private DataTable GetChartDataFees() {
               if (ddlyear.SelectedValue == "All") {
                DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
                try {
                 SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                 SqlDataAdapter sqlCmd = new SqlDataAdapter("GetFeeStatistics", sqlCon);
                 sqlCmd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                 sqlCon.Open();

                 sqlCmd.Fill(dsData);

                 sqlCon.Close();
                } catch {
                 throw;
                }
                return dsData.Tables[0];
               } else {
                DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
                try {
                 SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                 SqlDataAdapter sqlCmd = new SqlDataAdapter("GetFeeStatisticsYear", sqlCon);
                 sqlCmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", ddlyear.SelectedValue);
                 sqlCmd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                 sqlCon.Open();

                 sqlCmd.Fill(dsData);

                 sqlCon.Close();
                } catch {
                 throw;
                }
                return dsData.Tables[0];
               }
              }

              private DataTable GetChartDataResult() {
               if (ddlyear.SelectedValue == "All") {
                DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
                try {
                 SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                 SqlDataAdapter sqlCmd = new SqlDataAdapter("GetResultStatistics", sqlCon);
                 sqlCmd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                 sqlCon.Open();

                 sqlCmd.Fill(dsData);

                 sqlCon.Close();
                } catch {
                 throw;
                }
                return dsData.Tables[0];
               } else {
                DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
                try {
                 SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                 SqlDataAdapter sqlCmd = new SqlDataAdapter("GetResultStatisticsYear", sqlCon);
                 sqlCmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", ddlyear.SelectedValue);
                 sqlCmd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                 sqlCon.Open();

                 sqlCmd.Fill(dsData);

                 sqlCon.Close();
                } catch {
                 throw;
                }
                return dsData.Tables[0];
               }
              }

              protected void ddlyear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
               //call BindChartFees
               BindChartFees();
               //call BindChartResult
               BindChartResult();
              }

              private static DataTable GetData(string query) {
               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
               String constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
               SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
               SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
               cmd.Connection = con;
               sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
               sda.Fill(dt);
               return dt;
              }
             }
```

## ASP.NET

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="panel">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlyear" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlyear_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="panel">
            <div>
                <asp:Literal ID="ltScripts" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <div id="fee_chart" style="width: auto; height: 500px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="panel">
            <div>
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <div id="result_chart" style="width: auto; height: 500px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DespeiL One is using `fee_chart` is it not? This line of code? `strScript.Append(@ "var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('fee_chart'));          
           chart.draw(data, options);`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem in `BindChartResult` I needed to change `ltScripts.Text = strScript.ToString();` to `Literal1.Text = strScript.ToString();` to correspond to the `Literal` control in my aspx file.